# Matplotlib not showing point in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Using Python 3 in PyCharm on Windows 10

I have a list of tuples that I need to plot. But the matplotlib is showing an empty graph:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.use('TkAgg')

input = [(1, 6), (4, 15), (7, 7), (10, 13), (11, 6),
         (11, 18), (11, 21), (12, 10), (15, 18),
         (16, 6), (18, 3), (18, 12), (19, 15), (22, 19)]


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


input_points = []
for array_x, array_y in input:
    input_points.append(Point(array_x, array_y))
    plt.plot(array_x, array_y)
plt.show()
```

How to get the points to show up and plotted in the graph?

Comment: I can get the dots to show, but the lines do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw lines, `plt.plot` needs a list (or numpy array) of x-positions and a list of y-positions. The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) lists the different options to draw markers and/or lines.

[List comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) is a handy way to extract x or y positions from a list of xy-coordinates.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input_points = [(1, 6), (4, 15), (7, 7), (10, 13), (11, 6),
                (11, 18), (11, 21), (12, 10), (15, 18),
                (16, 6), (18, 3), (18, 12), (19, 15), (22, 19)]
array_x = [x for x, y in input_points]
array_y = [y for x, y in input_points]
plt.plot(array_x, array_y, marker='o', color='crimson', linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```